# How to use an async calling inside of an RxJs Observable constructor

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am setting up an `effect` in an application using NgRx.

During the effect, I need to get some store values, do some logic, and then dispatch one or more actions as a result of the logic I run.

So, to make is easier, I am using an effect with `dispatch: false`.

```ts
public getCachedOrServerValue$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(myActions.getCachedOrServerValue),
      switchMap((_) => this.getCachedOrServerValue())
    ), { dispatch: false }
);
```

So in the above I will call `getCachedOrServerValue`. I want to use `switchMap` (rather than just `tap`) so if I get a new `myActions.getCachedOrServerValue` before the previous has finished, it will cancel the previous subscription (from what I understand about switchMap).

The function that we call looks like the following:

```ts
private getCachedOrServerValue(): Observable<void> {
  const result$ = new Observable<void>(async (subscriber) => { // <---- I need this to be async so I can use await
    // First see if we can get it from the store
    const cached = await this.storeUtils.getStoreValue(fromApp.getValue);
    if (cached) {
      this.store$.dispatch(myActions.getCachedOrServerValueSuccess(cached));
      subscriber.next();
      return;
    }

    // Need to request from the server
    const name = await this.storeUtils.getStoreValue(fromApp.getSiteName);

    // storeUtils.getStoreValue is just a helper we have to get a single value as a Promise
    const valueId = await this.storeUtils.getStoreValue(fromApp.getValueId);
    const serverValue = await this.myService.getValue(namevalueId);
    this.store$.dispatch(myActions.storeValue(serverValue));
    this.store$.dispatch(myActions.getCachedOrServerValueSuccess(cached));
  });
  return result$;
}
```

First, I wrap in an observable, as from what I can remember we need an observable to use this call within `switchMap`.

Second (my actual problem), I want to be able to use `await` inside the Observable `subscriber` constructor argument, but VSCode is reporting an error.

[image]

Error details:

> Argument of type '(this: Observable, subscriber: Subscriber) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Observable, subscriber: Subscriber) => TeardownLogic'.
> Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'TeardownLogic'.
> Property 'unsubscribe' is missing in type 'Promise' but required in type 'Unsubscribable'.ts(2345)

types.d.ts(31, 5): 'unsubscribe' is declared here.

What is the problem here, and how I can use the `aysnc/await` as shown above?

### Update

Going from @StPaulis answer, I can avoid having to do this (at least in this situation).

I can do it like the following (not tested yet, but am sure will be fine):

```
public getCachedOrServerValue$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(myActions.getCachedOrServerValue),
    switchMap(_ => from(this.getCachedOrServerValue()).pipe( // <-- use a from here 
         map(data => myActions.getCachedOrServerValueSuccess(data)),
         catchError(error => of(myActions.getCachedOrServerValueFail(error)))
))));

private async getCachedOrServerValue(): Promise<DataState>{
 // First see if we can get it from the store
 const cached = await this.storeUtils.getStoreValue(fromApp.getValue);
 if (cached) {
    return cached;
 }

 // Need to request from the server
 const name = await this.storeUtils.getStoreValue(fromApp.getName);
 const valueId = await this.storeUtils.getStoreValue(fromApp.getValueId);
 const serverValue = await this.myService.getValue(name, valueId);
 return serverValue;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use the normal promise's `.then`? The flow inside the observable's function parameter will be easy to achieve with normal promise behavior instead of `async|await`.

Let me know if you need help to achieve it

Comment: Yes, if I can't get the async/await, I will just use the .then (and I am fine to do that), Was just wanted to see if the above was possible. I actually use to do it in an older v8 project using Observable.create (but it is now marked obsolete in v12)

Comment: I suppose the constructor just doesn't support it then. Good Q though. Will upvote, maybe the RXJS team will see it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, mixing observables with promises is never a good idea.

I suggest you to use [RxJs | from](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from) to convert your promise to an observable and use it inside your pipe instead of creating a new observable and wrapping all the logic inside.

Comment: Hmm, ok. In the past I have found it ok (when I had async await), So as an alternative, as I get a couple for values from the store via the selects, and then a promise from a service call, I just have all the observables (using the `from` for the service call) , and perhaps use `combineLatest` on them all? I have currently chained the promises (.`thens`), which is much less readable... so I might refactor and try that.. i.e. use all Observables...

Comment: Ah, now I understand! I should just have the helper method return a promise, and then use  the `from` in the main effects creation. I can then use async/await in the helper - and  have done this before, not sure why I missed it this time. Though not tested yet, I've put what this would like like as an edit. Thankyou.